# Mods to install before starting Fallout New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, mods

I have just bought Fallout New Vegas. I read the patch notes and I saw that many bug as been fixed after the release.

What I am wondering now is, if there are any known bugs and if there are **mods I should install to fix them**, before starting my adventure in New Vegas.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are many mods that fix actual bugs in F:NV, but they fix many of the annoying things. Look at [New Vegas Nexus](http://www.newvegasnexus.com/) for example for mods to install.

My main concern is the User Interface which is just horrible in every way (at least on PC). Increasing the amount of information that can be displayed at the same time does a lot.

Mods I have installed:

- [MTUI](http://www.newvegasnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=34902)
- [Inventory sorter](http://www.newvegasnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=38604)
- There's also one that shows all health stats in one mouse over screen, but I can find it.
- I'm on my second play through so I installed some cheat to simplify hacking as well.

I'd suggest start playing as normal, and then install mods that help areas that annoy you.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've not encountered any major bugs in New Vegas aside from 1 crash (touch wood) so I'd probably say don't bother with the mods. Chances are they will increase the risk of encountering issues anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one mentioned this. Similar to the Fallout 3 Unofficial Patch, there's one Mod called [YUP (Yukichigai Unofficial Patch)](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/51664/?).

It supplies fixes to things that were meant to work in the vanilla game, but didn't. It's not new content, just a nice pile of fixes.

Examples:

- Fixes the Dead Money perk In Shining Armor so that it actually does
  something
- Corrects the female mesh for the Pimp-Boy 3 Billion so that    it's
  not held at an angle
- Fixes Boone's head tracking and stops him    from holstering his
  weapon every 5 seconds in combat
- Alters Fixer so    that it cures addiction temporarily as it says,
  not permanently
- Ultrajet addiction can now be cured by doctors
- Stops various NPCs and    creatures who begin the game dead from
  miraculously resurrecting 3    days later
- Ensures the Brotherhood of Steel Explosive Collar won't    detonate
  after its removed from your neck
- Prevents the Old World    Blues trait Skilled from being taken, then
  removed to leave a    permanent +5 to all skills